What Reactor frames in inteliji idea debugger mean
I am currently working on a Java Reactor project (in intelij Idea) and have encountered something in the debugger that is marked as a "reactor frame" (as shown in the image). I am having trouble understanding what it signifies and how it is related to common frames. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could explain this to me. Thank you

This is part of IntelliJ's Reactor Debug mode functionality.
In reactive projects, it can be difficult to see where a call comes from because you are typically telling reactor to execute code later. Hence the previous/parent calls are not in the call stack.
This feature should show you these calls (somewhat) as if you synchronously executed them. I think that if you double-click on these reactive frames, you should see the code associated with them.
Note that this is only available in the paid "Ultimate Edition".

Thank you for your replay!
So as i understand Java reactor frames have no connection with common frames?

Both reactive frames and actual stack frames describe how your code got called. However, stack frames show you a (somewhat) low-level information (which is normally more than enough for non-reactive applications) of how it is called while reactive frames are an abstraction showing you an additional logical view.
